# Getting a Regex exception on using replaceAll in String

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string where I have to replace a certain text with the values that I receive as an input from user.

```
String input = "Hello dear {{user.salutation}} {{user.name}},"
```

I need to replace `{{user.salutation}}` with `Mr.` and so on.

I tried using replaceAll method in java that takes in a regex function

```
input.replaceAll("{{user.salutation}}","Mr.")
```

However, I keep on getting an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{{user.salutation}}
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1997)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3294)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2183)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2038)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1760)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1409)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1065)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2125)
```

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong in my regex pattern. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
input.replaceAll("{{user.salutation}}","Mr.")
```

to

```
   input.replaceAll("\\{\\{user.salutation\\}\\}","Mr.")
    or
   input.replaceAll("\\{\\{user.salutation}}","Mr.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` expects to get regex, if you want to escape the curly brackets you can replace the code to:

```
String newInput = input.replaceAll("\\{\\{user\\.salutation}}","Mr.");
```

You can use `replace` instead (It is the same as `replaceAll` without the regex issue)

```
String newInput = input.replace("{{user.salutation}}", "Mr.");
```